# Laravel Join Related Product Images

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

`product`: `id | name | category`

`productimage`: `id | imagename | productid`

I want to take results in this form:

```
[{
 "id":1,
 "name":"abc",
 "category":1,
 "imagename":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "imagename":abc.jpg
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "imagename":abc1.jpg
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "imagename":abc2.jpg
    }]
}]
```

and I have two models:

`call`:

```
= product
= productimage

<?php

class Product extends \Eloquent {
    //protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'product';


    public function productimage(){
        return $this->hasMany('productimage');
    }

}

<?php

class Productimage extends \Eloquent {
    //protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'productimage';

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('product');
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried?

Comment: You should read about relationships in the Laravel documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: It isn't really clear what your problem is, or your question... Read the documentation, try, and ask when you run into a specific problem.

Comment: my problem don't know how to join product::find(id)->productimage;

Answer (score 0):

This is taken directly from the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships):

Define the relationship in the model, i assume that one product can only have one product image:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function productimage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Productimage');
    }

}
```

Get product image for the product with ID of 1:

```
$image = Product::find(1)->productimage;
```